# "At the most difficult times" or "in the most difficult times"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

In the example below which preposition is appropriate: *at* or *in*?

> Family will be there for you **[at/in]** the most difficult times no
>   matter what.

Comment: Either would work, but I have a marked preference for *at*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *At difficult times* refers to difficult **moments** - points in time.
- *In difficult times* generally refers to difficult time **periods**. (But it can also refer to moments.)

So if you want to emphasize moments then use *at*; if you want to emphasize periods then use *in*.

And of course the notion/perception of what constitutes a moment in time versus a period of time is subjective or variable. A family crisis might generally be thought of as a moment, whereas prolonged economic hardship might be thought of as a period. It really all depends on how you want to portray the difficult time spent, relative to the other, ordinary time periods.